# Content of element disappear after updating different element

Tags: jquery, html

When I click a box the title of clicked box disappear after updating content of different element. Any idea why? Content of clicked box should remain intact.

[http://jsfiddle.net/wdQ6j/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/wdQ6j/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="school_left_box">
    <p class="register_title">School</p>This is a box
</div>

<div id="representative_left_box">
    <p class="register_title">Representative</p>This is a box
</div>

<p class="register_title form">Hello</p>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#school_left_box").click(function()
    {
        var title = $(".register_title", this);

        $("#hidden_registration_type").html('School');
        $(".register_title.form").html(title);
        $("#register_right_box").fadeIn(300);
    });

    $("#representative_left_box").click(function()
    {
        var title = $(".register_title", this);

        $("#hidden_registration_type").html('Representative');
        $(".register_title.form").html(title);
        $("#register_right_box").fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of copying the content of title, you are moving the title element, try `var title = $(".register_title", this).html()`

```
$("#school_left_box").click(function() {
    var title = $(".register_title", this).html();

    $("#hidden_registration_type").html('School');
    $(".register_title.form").html(title);
    $("#register_right_box").fadeIn(300);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CjMEF/)